# Which is better for an Invitations designer Corel Draw or Illistrator? Or are they pretty close to the same?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw, stock-images

I am an aspiring designer. I want to make event invitations and stationary for weddings and such. Which of these programs would be better? And why? What are the major differences?

Also, can you use Adobe Stock images in Corel Draw?

Comment: Mac or Windows? Also, when you say 'aspiring', how much experience do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Corel Draw and Illustrator can do each other's jobs well.

There are some difference however that are quite big and may influence your decision.

**Platform**

Illustrator is available for both Mac and Windows PCs. But Corel is only available on Windows.

**Price**

Corel Draw is a lot cheaper than Illustrator.

**Illustrator is Industry standard.**

You will find a lot more places using Adobe than Corel.

**Corel Draw has massive canvases**

Illustrator has a maximum canvas size of 5 meters x 5 meters. Which is a lot larger than most people will need to use, but for a sign maker (like myself) its annoying.

**Illustrator handles colours and opacities a lot better**

I hate when exporting files that contain opacities and shadows in Corel Draw only to have the result look totally different. Although Corel has a lot of colour profiling options, its not as good as Illustrator.

These are the major differences, there are others. There are tools like the perspective grid in Illustrator but not in Corel. The bevel, drop shadow and other effect tools are a little easier to use in Illustrator.

Personally I think Illustrator is well suited to web and print graphics. Corel Draw is better suited to sign making, CNC, engraving etc.

For your specific need I'd go for Illustrator.

Stock Images are universal and an be used on any design software.